# Gridview checkbox is checked=false even when its been checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, controls

I have a gridview that is populated with a datatable and has an item template with a checkbox in it. Even when the checkbox is checked, the cs code says checked=false.

Asp:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gvListOfPages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false">
                        <Columns>  
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPages" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PageName" />                           
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gvListOfPages.Rows)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chk = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkPages");
        if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
        {
            int arrayIndex = Convert.ToInt32(chk.ID.Substring(chk.ID.Length - 1, chk.ID.Length));
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is not quite enough information given to make a good call. What method is this foreach located in? Also, when is the gridview populated? Perhaps, page load?

Comment: I ask because i'm guessing this is a timing issue.

Comment: From what I can infer from your description your code should work. Is possible there is server side code that is rebinding the source data when posting back and thereby re-initialising check-box control states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkPages")
```

to

```
(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPages")
```

There is no need to specify cell when you are using `FindControl`. You might be probably hitting `chk != null` condition.
And if that's not the case then make sure that you are binding your `GridView` at `Page_Load` inside `!IsPostBack` like this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Bind your grid here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.